# Common characters within strings in 2 lists in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have 2 lists as follows:

```
a = ["Ron is great", "Mark is good", "Sheela is bad", "Amy is horrible"]
b = ["Ron", "Mark"]
c = [item for item in a if item in b]
```

I normally use the above list comprehension to find common elements between 2 lists.However it fails in the above scenario as the IN function does an exact match and hence c is an empty list.How do I circumvent this and try to get a list c which looks like this :

```
c=["Ron is great", "Mark is good"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need two loops, for instance

```
c = [item for item in a
     if any(name in item for name in b)]
```

should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem solved with list expressions

```
>>> a = ["Ron is great", "Mark is good", "Sheela is bad", "Amy is horrible"]
>>> b = ["Ron", "Mark"]
>>> c= [
...     sentence
...     for word in b
...     for sentence in a
...     if word in sentence
... ]                

['Ron is great', 'Mark is good']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
>>> a = ["Ron is great", "Mark is good", "Sheela is bad", "Amy is horrible"]
>>> b = ["Ron", "Mark"]
>>> [ item for item in a for word in b if word in item]
['Ron is great', 'Mark is good']
>>>
```